# Netty 4.0.30.Final channel write issue

Tags: java, netty

I have written an encoder that does encode the message I am sending on the wire. In my handler I issued the the ctx.writeAndFlush() method but nothing seems to be written to the remote endpoint. These are my code snippets:

### Encoder

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class FreeSwitchEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<BaseCommand> {

    /**
     * Logger property
     */
    private final Logger _log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    /**
     * Character set delimiting the end of each FreeSwitch message parts
     */
    private final String MESSAGE_END_STRING = "\n\n";
    private final Charset _encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, BaseCommand msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {

        // Get the string representation of the BaseCommand
        String toSend = msg.toString().trim();

        // Let us check whether the command ends with \n\n
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(toSend)) {
            if (!toSend.endsWith(MESSAGE_END_STRING)) toSend = toSend + MESSAGE_END_STRING;
            _log.debug("Encoded message sent [{}]", toSend);

            ByteBuf encoded = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(toSend.getBytes());
           // encoded = encoded.capacity(encoded.readableBytes());
            out.writeBytes(encoded);
        }
    }
}
```

### The code that sends the message

```
public FreeSwitchMessage sendCommand(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                     final BaseCommand command) {
    ManuelResetEvent manuelResetEvent = new ManuelResetEvent();
    syncLock.lock();
    try {
        manuelResetEvents.add(manuelResetEvent);
        _log.debug("Command sent to freeSwitch [{}]", command.toString());
       ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(command);
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if(!future.isSuccess()){
                    future.cause().printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } finally {
        syncLock.unlock();
    }

    // Block until the response is available
    return manuelResetEvent.get();
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The code hangs at the writting to the wire. Please assist. This is the log:

```
06:53:44.417 [main] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
06:53:44.421 [main] DEBUG i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
06:53:44.432 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
06:53:44.432 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
06:53:44.433 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
06:53:44.433 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
06:53:44.433 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
06:53:44.434 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Java version: 8
06:53:44.434 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
06:53:44.434 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
06:53:44.434 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
06:53:44.435 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Javassist: unavailable
06:53:44.435 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - You don't have Javassist in your class path or you don't have enough permission to load dynamically generated classes.  Please check the configuration for better performance.
06:53:44.435 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\smsgh\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
06:53:44.436 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
06:53:44.436 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
06:53:44.458 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
06:53:44.459 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
06:53:44.487 [main] INFO  io.freeswitch.OutboundTest - Client connecting ..
06:53:44.517 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.ThreadLocalRandom - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0xf77d8a3de122380b (took 9 ms)
06:53:44.559 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
06:53:44.559 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
06:53:44.591 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
06:53:44.596 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 262144
06:53:44.599 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.codecs.FreeSwitchDecoder - read header line [Content-Type: auth/request]
06:53:44.601 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.message.FreeSwitchMessage - adding header [CONTENT_TYPE] [auth/request]
06:53:44.601 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.codecs.FreeSwitchDecoder - read header line []
06:53:44.602 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.Cleaner0 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
06:53:44.602 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - Discarded inbound message FreeSwitchMessage: contentType=[auth/request] headers=1, body=0 lines. that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
06:53:44.603 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.outbound.OutboundHandler - Received message: [FreeSwitchMessage: contentType=[auth/request] headers=1, body=0 lines.]
06:53:44.607 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.outbound.OutboundHandler - Auth requested, sending [auth *****]
06:53:44.683 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.outbound.OutboundHandler - Command sent to freeSwitch [auth ClueCon]
06:53:44.683 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG i.f.codecs.FreeSwitchEncoder - Encoded message sent [auth ClueCon

]
```

Comment: where flush in FreeSwitchEncoder ?

Comment: @Rustam Do I need to to do writeFlush in the encoder?

Comment: At least you can try. Do you have another handlers in chain?

Comment: I have tried it . It still hangs. In the chain I have an Inbound handler.

Comment: I observed some kind of inifinite loop going on while I was in debug mode.